# Store data on server and set in array for local function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I work's on the ShoopingApp in Angular and for backend I using FireBase.
I have model category:

```
import { ProductModel } from "./product.model";

export class CategoryModel {

public id: number;
public name: string;
public description: string;
public image: string;
public products?: ProductModel[];


constructor(id: number, name: string, desciption: string, image: string, products: ProductModel[]) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desciption;
    this.image = image;
    this.products = products;
}
}
```

I setup service data-storage-service.ts for catching  and storing data from FireBase.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
}

@Injectable()
export class DataStorageServiceService {


  private heroesUrl = 'https://ng-recipefirebaseio.com/application.json';
  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  storeCategoryList(productList: CategoryModel): Observable<CategoryModel> {
    return this.http.post<CategoryModel>(this.heroesUrl, productList).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<CategoryModel>('addCategory'))

    )


  }
  getHeroes(): Observable<CategoryModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<CategoryModel[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
      );
  }


  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

         return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

I setup admin component, and i setup Modal from ngx-bootstrap. From this Modals I want send data to server. I using Reactive Forms for validation. 
Admin component look :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  category = <CategoryModel>{};


  //  category: CategoryModel[] = [];
  categoryList: CategoryModel[] = []
  categoryForm: FormGroup;
  modalRef: BsModalRef;


  constructor(private productsService: ProductsService, private dataStorageServiceService: DataStorageServiceService, private modalService: BsModalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCategory();
    this.initForm();

  }


  getCategory(): void {
    this.dataStorageServiceService.getCategory()
      .subscribe(category => this.categoryList = category);
  }



  storeCategoryList() {
    const nameCategory = this.categoryForm.value.name;
    const descriptionCategory = this.categoryForm.value.category;
    this.category.name = nameCategory;
    this.category.description = descriptionCategory;
    this.category.id = 1;
    this.category.products = null;
    this.dataStorageServiceService.storeCategoryList(this.category).subscribe(

      (category: CategoryModel) => {
        this.categoryList.push(category)
      }

    )
  }

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }

  private initForm() {
    this.categoryForm = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'description': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    })
  }


}
```

I have problem when I want to store data  in list `categoryList`, eoror is `ERROR TypeError: _this.categoryList.push is not a function`. And in FireBase store like this:

[image]

And method `getCategory()` return this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the methodname "getCategory" I guess the method returns a single category. This leads to your categoryList not being an array at runtime and thus not having a push method which leads to the error you are getting.

Comment: What does "getCategory" return? Can you post the method? I want to check if my guess is right, then I can tell you, I had a similar problem a while ago.